# Why am I getting an integer to pointer conversion error in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am looping through an NSString object called `previouslyDefinedNSString` and verifying if the integer representing the ASCII value of a letter is in an NSMutableSet called `mySetOfLettersASCIIValues`, which I had previously populated with NSIntegers:

```
NSInteger ASCIIValueOfLetter;

    for (int i; i < [previouslyDefinedNSString length]; i++) {

        ASCIIValueOfLetter = [previouslyDefinedNSString characterAtIndex:i];

        // if character ASCII value is in set, perform some more actions...
        if ([mySetOfLettersASCIIValues member: ASCIIValueOfLetter])
```

However, I am getting this error within the condition of the IF statement.

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to parameter of type 'id';
Implicit conversion of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'id' is disallowed with ARC
```

What do these errors mean? How am I converting to an object type (which id represents, right?)? Isn't NSInteger an object?

Comment: `member:` presumably expects an `id`.  You're giving it an integer.

Comment: Okay, so the problem here is that a set must contain objective-c objects and not scalar values like NSInteger.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You want to make it an NSNumber, as in:

```
NSInteger ASCIIValueOfLetter;

    for (int i; i < [previouslyDefinedNSString length]; i++) {

        ASCIIValueOfLetter = [previouslyDefinedNSString characterAtIndex:i];

        // if character ASCII value is in set, perform some more actions...
        if ([mySetOfLettersASCIIValues member: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: ASCIIValueOfLetter]])
```

Now you're going to have the result you're looking for.

Comment: How bizarre... my solution was initWithStyle: [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UITableViewCellStyleDefault], instead of initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault

Answer (score 11):

These errors mean that `member:` expects an object. `id` is a pointer to an Objective-C object, and instead of an object, you're passing in a primitive type, or scalar (despite its `NS-` prefix, `NSInteger` is not an object - just a `typedef` to a primitive value, and in your case, an `int`). What you need to do is wrap that scalar value in an object, and specifically, `NSNumber`, which is a class specifically designed to handle this.

Instead of calling `member:` with `ASCIIValueOfLetter`, you need to call it with the wrapped value, `[NSNumber numberWithInteger:ASCIIValueOfLetter]`, as Maurício mentioned.